# Is the sun supposed to be able to steal away your memories in Rings of Akhenaten?

Tags: doctor-who

Spoilers! Maybe.

Just seen the episode *The Rings Of Akhenaten* - didn't pay much attention, but it seemed to me that it is greatly implied that this God thing can consume your memories.

Given that the Doctor literally gave himself away to the sun (and it attacked him), one would suppose that the sun did drain something out from the Doctor. But, after these events, he seems to be perfectly fine.

Was the sun supposed to actually be able to steal away your memories? If yes, how did the Doctor survive just fine? If not, well, that monster is not quite a big deal... I thought it'd "destroy" the seven planets, but that makes no sense if all he wants is to eat memories.

Answer (score 1):

Wasn't a sun, more of a glowing planet.

Rest of the episode was unclear.

Seems the young singer, Merrin, was bred and trained to be fed to the godthing. But it wasn't clear if it physically ate her or just her memories.

Also not clear if eating memories causes the loss of memory in the memory donor, or if it is more like sharing experiences. Certainly, the leaf was destroyed when its potential for storing future memories of unhappened events was sucked dry. But why that was only a godlike planet thing can understand.

At the end, the doctor's memory did not seem to be compromised in any way, so probably no.